# Import Bulk Attribute Options in Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, importexport, attribute-options

i am using Magento 1.9.2.3 version. I have a brand attribute and i want to import all its option through csv file. Is there any way to import bulk attribute option?

thanks

Comment: nothing i don't have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I did this work with programmatically approach, but you can use below extension:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-export-product-attributes-by-magerips.html